# Adicionar "filter" no "logger" para a aplicação inteira

Tags: java, log, filter

Gostaria de fazer com que o `Filter` do `java.util.logging.Logger` filtrasse todas as linhas de log geradas. No caso, estou utilizando um servidor de aplicação Wildfly.

Atualmente, consigo filtrar apenas uma classe específica, por exemplo.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Classe.class.getName());
logger.setFilter(new MeuFiltro());
```

Ou seja, ao invés de filtrar apenas uma classe, gostaria de filtrar tudo e isso precisa ser feito programaticamente, pois, realizar alteração no XML do Wildfly não será viável.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa pegar o logger raiz:

```
Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
```

Comment: Legal, rea isso mesmo. 

Apenas, para solucionar de vez, ao invés de precisar do Filter, na verdade eu estava precisando utilizar o Handler. Mas de qualquer forma, a sua resposta fazia parte da solução.